# How to use BootstrapVue - Modal inside v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I am trying to use BootstrapVue - Modal inside v-for loop and the only problem is with modal directive ( v-b-modal.modal1 ) on a modal button. modal1 should be the name of modal id and since I am using a loop I am passing index in modal for example modal + index, but I don't know how to change buttons directive to be v-b-modal-modal1 ... v-b-modal-modal5.

This is modal component

```
    <template>
    <div>
        //This v-b-modal.modal1 should be same as modalId
        <b-btn v-b-modal.modal1>Banka: {{ data.offer.client_name }}</b-btn>
        <!-- Modal Component -->
        <b-modal :id="modalId" title="Oferta">
            <p clas="my-4">Kampanja: {{ data.offer.campaign_name }}</p>
            <p clas="my-4">Norma e interesit: {{ data.offer.interest_rate_nominal }}</p>
            <p clas="my-4">*Shpenzimet Administrative: {{ data.offer.admin_fee }}</p>
            <p clas="my-4">Kësti Mujor: {{ data.offer.monthly_payment }}</p>
        </b-modal>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    export default {
    props: ['data'],
    computed:{
      modalId(){
          return 'modal' + this.data.i;
      }
    }
   }
  </script>
```

Here is a method that uses modal

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(offer, i) in offers">
    <td>
      <app-show-details :data="{offer, i}"></app-show-details>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BootStrapVue provides more than one pattern to achieve modal](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal), so you don't have to insist on directive modifiers, I think using directive value fits your requirement here perfectly. Check sample code below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    modalId(i) {
      return 'modal' + i;
    }
  }
});

// or check jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5sv805ho/
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@next/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="i in 3">
    <b-btn v-b-modal="modalId(i)">Launch demo modal</b-btn>
    <b-modal :id="'modal' + i" title="Bootstrap-Vue">
      <p clas="my-4">Hello from modal {{ i }}!</p>
    </b-modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, [you can also use show() and hide() component methods](https://jsfiddle.net/qapfotqe/).